# python: for loop dictionary print out item

Tags: python

I have a data like this

print items

```
[{'end_date': u'2014-08-25','link': u'http://www.tt.tw/1','start_date': u'2014-08-01'},    
{'end_date': u'2014-08-26','link': u'http://www.tt.tw/2','start_date': u'2014-08-03'},         
{'end_date': u'2014-08-23','link': u'http://www.tt.tw/3','start_date': u'2014-08-01'}]
```

And I want to print out the link like this
How can I do?

output:

```
http://www.tt.tw/1
http://www.tt.tw/2 
http://www.tt.tw/3
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop with a `print` statement ... ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to show you teh codez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
values_list = [{'end_date': u'2014-08-25','link': u'http://www.tt.tw/1','start_date':    u'2014-08-01'},    
{'end_date': u'2014-08-26','link': u'http://www.tt.tw/2','start_date': u'2014-08-03'},         
{'end_date': u'2014-08-23','link': u'http://www.tt.tw/3','start_date': u'2014-08-01'}]

for dictionary in values_list:
    print dictionary['link']
```